# Bootstrap Modal min height not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple bootstrap modal where i am trying to set the min height and it is not working.

Here is the html:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="adminManagerModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Admin Manager</h4>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#managePlayers">Manage Players</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#manageTournaments">Manage Tournaments</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="managePlayers" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                        <button id="btnAddPlayer" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Add Player</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="manageTournaments" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <form>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input id="optUSCF" type="radio" name="optPlayerType" checked>USCF</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input id="optFIDE" type="radio" name="optPlayerType">FIDE</label>
                        </form>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note the id of the modal is "adminManagerModal"

Here is the css:

```
#adminManagerModal
{
    min-height:500px;
}
```

I have found other questions on here just like this and nothing i have tried seems to work. Any idea on what i am doing wrong would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle so that I can check it myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
#adminManagerModal .modal-content
{
    min-height:500px;
}
```

Demo [modal](https://jsfiddle.net/r3ux9x7a/)

Comment: Could you show how you want it to look?, add a fiddle

Comment: `min-height: 780px !important;` solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#adminManagerModal .modal-content
{
  min-height:500px;
}
```

Comment: Oops karritos did it first. I din't saw his answered 3 mins ago, my bad.